# Mongodb query needed

Tags: sql, mongodb, union

I need a query for mongodb with "union", I have two tables, blacklistSites and logs. BlacklistSites table has id, type, url and so on, and logs has id, url, url_dominio, etc. I need check which logs is in blacklistsites by url.

blacklistsites.url like logs.url_dominio

Ex:

url: http://www.example.com/page/article/post

url_dominio: http://www.example.com   or    example.com

Please help...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It sounds like what you need is an INNER JOIN, not a union - which is easier to do in a relational database than a nosql database like mongo. If you must use mongo, you will probably be better off setting a "blacklisted" attribute when the document is inserted.

Comment: This idea is good but I think I have to check if the log (url) is in the blacklist collection any way. I have been reading this days mongo documentation, in the last versions seems that I can do with the aggregate framework